# React.js -- How to pass properties object to child component?

Tags: javascript, properties, parent-child, reactjs

I have a component called `tileGroup` that has a property that is a collection(array) of other properties.

The parent component(`tileGroup`) renders a list of child components by using each set of properties in the collection to create a new component.

Right now I am individually mapping each property from the set to the child component but this will become cumbersome if the property count for a component increases and I'm sure there is a cleaner, simpler way to do it...

**How can I pass the full set of properties on to the child component without remapping each property?**

Example code:

```
tileGroupData = {someProperty: 'something', someOtherProperty:'something', 
                tiles: [{vsize:1, hsize:2, etc...}, {vsize:2,hsize:3,title:'whatever'}]};
```

and then component creation..

```
var tileGroup = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
       var thechildren = this.props.tiles.map(function(tile)
       {
           //this is what I DON'T want to be doing. 
           return <tileSimple vsize = {tile.vsize} hsize = {tile.hsize} content = {tile.content}/>;

           //what I DO want to be doing
           return <tileSimple allTheProps = {tile}/>; 
       });
```

Answer (score 130, accepted):

Apparently transferPropsTo is being deprecated. With recent versions of React you can use JSX spread attributes:

```
return <tileSimple {...tile} />;
```

More info about this here: [Deprecating transferPropsTo](https://gist.github.com/sebmarkbage/a6e220b7097eb3c79ab7)

Answer (score 31):

For those use cases, the easiest thing is to fallback to the JS API instead of JSX.

```
return tileSimple(tile);
```

To understand why it works, look at the generated version of the version you want using the JSX Compiler tool ( http://facebook.github.io/react/jsx-compiler.html )

```
<tileSimple vsize = {tile.vsize} hsize = {tile.hsize} content = {tile.content}/>;
tileSimple( {vsize:  tile.vsize, hsize:  tile.hsize, content:  tile.content});
```

Comment: wouldn't just tileSimple(tile); work? Props are supposed to be immutable so I would suspect a simple object reference would suffice.

Comment: On React 13+, you'd use `React.createFactory(tileSimple)(tile);`. See http://fb.me/react-legacyfactory .

Comment: this will not work if you have to define a `key` while mapping over array of `titleSimple`s

Answer (score 6):

You can actually just do the following in your render

```
return this.transferPropsTo(<tileSimple />);
```

Answer (score 0):

What you propose doing,

```
return <tileSimple allTheProps={tile} />;
```

works just fine.

Within the `tileSimple` component you should then be able to access the properties using syntax like,

```
var vsize = this.props.allTheProps.vsize;
var hsize = this.props.allTheProps.hsize;
```

Comment: The problem with that solution is that I will have an ever-increasing set of "wrapper" properties I have to traverse just to go a few nodes down. The solution @Vjeux works though!

Comment: @MattFoxxDuncan I agree that @Vjeux solution is more elegant, however, I don't understand what you mean by an ever-increasing set of wrapper properties?  If you passed allTheProps to a child component, you'd still access it the same way (i.e., `this.props.childAllTheProps.vsize`).  What am I missing?

Comment: The component structure I am envisioning entails writing independent components(as is React's philosophy) but having them built by the parent component(if any) they belong to. In a scenario where I have Page Master -> Section -> Tile Group -> Tile(Type) -> Tile Content -> something else -- there is a potential for 5+ wrappers in that chain. This, then, would not be a reasonable object to have to traverse  `this.FirstChildPropsWrapper.SecondChildPropsWrapper.ThirdChildPropsWRapper.FourthChildPropsWrapper.etc`