# Is it possible in React to define which prop to pass (and whether to pass) to child components based on prop from parent component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend, react-props, web-frontend

Basically imagine the following situation, there are 4 existing components: `MainComponent1`, `MainComponent2`, `IntermediateComponent` and `ChildComponent`. `MainComponent1` and `MainComponent2` can use `IntermediateComponent` as their child component, and `ChildComponent` is a child component for `IntermediateComponent`.

Depending on which component is a parent component to `IntermediateComponent` the props that are being passed to the `ChildComponent` by `IntermediateComponent` can be either 1 out of 2 options, or there could be a case that some prop would be only applicable to `MainComponent1`'s descendant (as to indirect child through `IntermediateComponent`).

Is it possible to set up with React to setup something like this:

/* IntermediateComponent */

```
<ChildComponent
  color="primary"
  {mainProp === 'MAIN2' ? variant="contained" : variant="outlined"}>
   Example Title
</ChildComponent>
```

OR

```
<ChildComponent
  color="primary"
  {mainProp === 'MAIN2' ? variant="contained" : undefined}>
   Example Title
</ChildComponent>
```

I know that the following setup will not work, so please look at it as rather pseudocode, but basically what I'm trying to achieve is that depending on the value of one prop (`mainProp`) that is being passed from the `MainComponent1` or `MainComponent2` to determine whether some prop (`variant` in this case) that is being passed to the `ChildComponent`should have a particular value or should not be even passed.

I'm trying to combine 2 components in the app right now, which are similar in overall in structure but have to be passing different props to child components. What could be a better solution to implement such thing?

Comment: Yes you can try this
<ChildComponent
  color="primary"
  variant={maniProp === 'MAIN2'? 'contained' : 'undefined'}>
   Example Title
</ChildComponent>

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React.js -- How to pass properties object to child component?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20913288/react-js-how-to-pass-properties-object-to-child-component)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about simply setting value conditionally:

```
<ChildComponent
  color="primary"
  variant={mainProp === 'MAIN2' ? 'contained' : undefined}
>
   Example Title
</ChildComponent>
```

If things get more complicated you can always spread out:

```
<ChildComponent
  color="primary"
  ...(mainProp === 'MAIN2' ? { a: 10, b: 11 } : { y: 123 })
>
   Example Title
</ChildComponent>
```

*this will either add `a=10` and `b=11` or `y=123`*